# Return a Python object defined in a third party Python module (e.g. Numpy) using PyO3

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

#### Motivation

This question is framed in terms of a specific example, for concreteness, but it's part of a much bigger question of how to return objects in pyo3, generally.

#### Problem

I'm writing a python module with a Rust backend using PyO3.

I'd like to write a wrapper for a function that returns a rational number (of type `Ratio<isize>`); the wrapped function should return a Python `Fraction`. I'm not sure how to do this, but it would probably suffice to be able to reproduce the following function with PyO3 would be sufficient:

```py
import fractions

def divide( numer, denom ):
  return fractions.Fraction( numer, denom )
```

Currently my library just destructures a fraction into a pair of integers `(numer, denom)` and exports to python, then uses pure python wrapper code to reassemble the fraction, but this causes all sorts of organizational issues.

#### Prior attempts

The following is my latest (clearly wrong) attempt.

```
pub fn export_fraction( numer: isize, denom: isize  ) 
        -> 
        PyResult< PyAny >  {

        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let frac = py.import("fractions").ok().unwrap();
            Ok(frac.call_method("Fraction",( numer, denom),None) )

        }) 
}
```

The error message is a mismatch for the return type; I've tried playing around with it but my ability to parse the various `Result`, `PyResult`, etc. types is too nubile.

```bash
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/simplex_filtered.rs:70:9
   |
68 |           PyResult< PyAny >  {
   |           ----------------- expected `Result<pyo3::PyAny, PyErr>` because of return type
69 |
70 | /         Python::with_gil(|py| {
71 | |             let frac = py.import("fractions").ok().unwrap();
72 | |             Ok(frac.call_method("Fraction",( numer, denom),None) )
73 | |
74 | |         }) 
   | |__________^ expected `Result<PyAny, PyErr>`, found `Result<Result<&PyAny, PyErr>, _>`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<pyo3::PyAny, PyErr>`
              found enum `Result<Result<&pyo3::PyAny, PyErr>, _>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PyAny` is a type that only exists within the `Python` environment so it has to be a reference, either one bound to a current GIL, but you have to pass in the `Python<'py>` instance in that case:

```rust
pub fn export_fraction_with_current_gil<'py>(py: Python<'py>, numer: isize, denom: isize) -> PyResult<&'py PyAny> {
    let frac = py.import("fractions")?;
    frac.call_method("Fraction", (numer, denom), None)
}
```

Or you use [`Py`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html) which is "A GIL-independent reference to an object allocated on the Python heap.":

```rust
pub fn export_fraction(numer: isize, denom: isize) -> PyResult<Py<PyAny>> {
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let frac = py.import("fractions")?;
        frac.call_method("Fraction", (numer, denom), None)
            .map(Into::into)
    })
}
```